# PHP regex lookbehind with wildcard

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have two strings in PHP:

```
$string  = '<a href="http://localhost/image1.jpeg" /></a>';
```

and

```
$string2 = '[caption id="attachment_5" align="alignnone" width="483"]<a href="http://localhost/image1.jpeg" /></a>[/caption]';
```

I'm trying to match strings of the first type. That is strings that are not surrounded by '[caption ... ]' and '[/caption]'. So far, I would like to use something like this:

```
$pattern = '/(?<!\[caption.*\])(?!\[\/caption\])(<a.*><img.*><\/a>)/';
```

but PHP matches out the first string as well with this pattern even though it is NOT preceeded by '[caption' and zero or more characters followed by ']'. What gives? Why is this and what's the correct pattern?

Thanks.

Comment: why dont you try to match strings that starts with <a?

Answer (score 0):

Variable length look-behind is not supported in PHP, so this part of your pattern is not valid:

```
(?<!\[caption.*\])
```

It should be warning you about this.

In addition, `.*` always matches the larges possible amount.  Thus your pattern may result in a match that overlaps multiple tags.  Instead, use `[^>]` (match anything that is not a closing bracket), because closing brackets should not occur inside the `img` tag.

To solve the look-behind problem, why not just check for the closing tag only?  This should be sufficient (assuming the caption tags are only used in a way similar to what you have shown).

```
$pattern = '|(<a[^>]*><img[^>]*></a>)(?!\[/caption\])|';
```

*When matching patterns that contain `/`, use another character as the pattern delimiter to avoid leaning toothpick syndrome. You can use nearly any non-alphanumeric character around the pattern.*

**Update:** the previous regex is based on the example regex you gave, rather than the example data.  If you want to match links that don't contain images, do this:

```
$pattern = '|(<a[^>]*>[^<]*</a>)(?!\[/caption\])|';
```

Note that this doesn't allow *any* tags in the middle of the link.  If you allow tags (such as by using `.*?`), a regex could match something starting within the `[caption]` and ending elsewhere.

Comment: Your solution won't match his first string `<a href="http://localhost/image1.jpeg" /></a>`.

Comment: @zb226, thanks for pointing that out.  There is a mismatch between the regex in the question and the sample data, and I based my answer on the regex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your regexp could match either string, since you're looking for `<a.*><img.*><\/a>`, and both anchors don't contain an `<img...` tag. Also, the two subexpressions looking for and prohibiting the `caption`-bits look oddly positioned to me. Finally, you need to ensure your tag-matching bits don't act greedy, i.e. don't use `.*` but `[^>]*`.

Do you mean something like this?

```
$pattern = '/(<a[^>]*>(<img[^>]*>)?<\/a>)(?!\[\/caption\])/'
```

Test it on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sH3aM5).

**Edit:** Removed useless lookahead as per dan1111's suggestion and updated regex101 link.

Answer (score -1):

Lookbehind doesn't allow non fixed length pattern i.e. (*,+,?), I think this `/<a.*><\/a>(?!\[\/caption\])/` is enough for your requirement

Comment: This is incorrect; the look-ahead needs to be at the point in the pattern you want it to match (the end of the string, not the beginning).  The negative look-ahead will always be satisfied because it starts looking at `<a....`.

Comment: try doing it in preg_match, i did it and it worked. Also test it here http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: It does not even exclude the example of what should not match in the question: http://regex101.com/r/kL8yC8 And it definitely won't work in a real-world example where the links are within a larger file.

Comment: @GeraldSv--if you actually go to the link I gave, you will see that the global option makes no difference (nor is there any reason to think it would--it controls the number of matches that are performed, not the behavior of a single match).

Comment: If you tested it on both strings with the global setting turned off, it would only match the first one.  But that is a coincidence, because it only matches one time and the string that should match happened to be first.